# How to remove array in array? AJAX data for json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have JSON data by api as per below OUTPUT:

```
[[{"first":1}],[{"last":0}],[{"other":4}]]
```

My Ajax code:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $.getJSON('/ytl/public/api/first-hour-trades', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(firstHourTrades, element) {
      $("#msg1").append($('<div>', {
        text: element.first
      }));
      $("#msg2").append($('<div>', {
        text: element.last
      }));
      $("#msg3").append($('<div>', {
        text: element.other
      }));

    });
  });
}, 10000);
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <p id='msg1'> first hour trades</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <p id='msg2'> last hour trades</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Force next columns to break to new line at md breakpoint and up -->
  <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block">
    <p id='msg3'> other hours trade</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Output of ajax is nothing. **I think there's problem is my JSON result but what to do and how to solve it?**

MY CODE:

```
$data = [$first_hour,$last_hour,$other_hours];

    return response()->json($data );
```

Comment: JSON, not Jason

Comment: try using `echo` instead of return

Comment: Is there an error message in the developer console?

Comment: Alos never use interval on Ajax - instead use setTimeout  from the succes handler

Comment: Are PHP errors on? You might get a 500 and not see it

Comment: According to your post, the data is an array of arrays. If that's accurate it should be `element[0].first` etc instead of just `element.first`.

Comment: echo is providing same result. @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: Yes that is array but, how can i remove array of arrays. I have done with `element[0].first` which is not giving result @Pointy

Comment: How can I setTimeout by handler, can you help me ? @mplungjan

Comment: `function callIt() { 
  $.getJSON('/ytl/public/api/first-hour-trades', function(data) {
    setTimeout(callIt,10000);
    $.each(data, function(firstHourTrades, element) {
      $("#msg1").append($('<div>', {
        text: element.first
      }));
      $("#msg2").append($('<div>', {
        text: element.last
      }));
      $("#msg3").append($('<div>', {
        text: element.other
      }));

    });
  });
}`

Comment: its two difficult to understand, can you post answer with this code will great ? @mplungjan

Comment: I just removed the setInterval and put the call in a function I call in the success. If there is a JSON error this will not help you.

Comment: Can you `dd($data)` on your controller, then tell me the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

```js
var jsonResult = JSON.parse('[[{"first":1}],[{"last":0}],[{"other":4}]]');

setInterval(function() {
  
    $.each(jsonResult, function(firstHourTrades, element) {
      $("#msg1").append($('<div>', {
        text: element[0].first
      }));  
      $("#msg2").append($('<div>', {
        text: element[0].last
      }));      
      /*
      $("#msg2").append($('<div>', {
        text: element.last
      }));
      */
    });
  
}, 10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <p id='msg1'> first hour trades</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
    <p id='msg2'> last hour trades</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is also not giving result.

Comment: Ok let me try. @Rogerio