# How to remove array in arrays from Variable?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to remove array from arrays but array is in `$variable`. I did not find any example which has array in array for `$variable`.

**Function:**

```
     public function firstHourTrades()
{

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $first_hour = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as first'))
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw('exchanges.start_time'))
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '01:00:00')"))
        ->get();


    $last_hour = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as last'))
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw('exchanges.close_time'))
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw("SUBTIME(exchanges.close_time, '01:00:00')"))
        ->get();


    $other_hours = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as other'))
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereRaw('finaltrade.created_at NOT BETWEEN exchanges.start_time AND DATE_ADD(exchanges.start_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)')
        ->whereRaw('finaltrade.created_at NOT BETWEEN exchanges.close_time AND DATE_SUB(exchanges.close_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)')
        ->get();

    $data = [$first_hour,$last_hour,$other_hours];
    return response()->json($data );
}
```

**OUTPUT** of above function :

```
[[{"first":1}],[{"last":0}],[{"other":4}]]
```

I want to remove array in array, **what i do in my function?**

Comment: Try giving an example of your desired output format.

Comment: maybe try `$data = [$first_hour[0],$last_hour[0],$other_hours[0]];` ?

Comment: Use first() instead of get() in your query builder.  get() returns a collection, first() returns the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your queries result as a single row which i guess yes because you are not using group by then you can use `first()` instead of `get()`

Output will be

```
[{"first":1},{"last":0},{"other":4}]
```

Comment: yes show this output ' [{"first":1},{"last":0},{"other":4}]'

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati I am unable to get your comment ? Are you getting this output using mentioned approach?

Comment: I am not getting output but, your answer is giving perfect result in removing error. @M Khalid

Comment: I asked this question because on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798231/how-to-remove-array-in-array-ajax-data-for-json?noredirect=1#comment88606190_50798231

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$prefs = 
[
    ['fruit' => 'banana'],
    ['nut' => 'pecan'],
    ['pasta' => 'fusili']
];

$flatter = array_merge(...$prefs);
var_export($flatter);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'fruit' => 'banana',
  'nut' => 'pecan',
  'pasta' => 'fusili',
)
```

Comment: thanks for asnwer @Progrock. Why did you given me down vote? Actually, I surf in google before asked question.

Comment: Why do you think I gave you the down vote?  I usually give a reason if I am to do that.  The cowardly lazy haters don't.

Comment: Oh! I am sorry. @Progrock